# Does Fallout 4 have a color filter like Fallout 3 and Fallout: New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-4, fallout-series

Previous 3D Fallout games Fallout 3 (green) and Fallout: New Vegas (orange) both have a color filter (filter enabled on left, disabled on right):

Fallout 3:

[image: Fallout 3]

New Vegas:

[image: New Vegas]

By looking at Fallout 4 screenshots, the game might have a blueish filter, if anything.

[image]
[image]

Does the game actually have a color filter?

Comment: What? What do those screenshots represent? Did a filter get removed in one, or something?

Comment: The top screenshot is fallout 3.  The left side is with the green filter, the right side is unfiltered.  The bottom screenshot is Fallout New Vegas. The left side is unfiltered, and the right side has the orange filter (to my eyes).  I know some mods have been made to remove these filters but I'm not sure about fallout 4

Comment: Are you asking if there's a color filter to change, or just one in place for the whole game?

Comment: @NBN-Alex: If there's a color filter as in FO3 and NV.

Comment: I can't really tell if you're asking a question or answering a question.

Comment: @Ellesedil: Asking for sure, I'm not sure if Fallout 4 uses a blue color filter.

Comment: @user598527 Timmy Jim answered my question for me. Obviously those were Fallout 3 and New Vegas. The missing detail is that a mod was used to remove a filter in each picture, and you were showing the contrast.

Comment: @TimmyJim: I mirrored New Vegas Image for consistency.

Comment: Based on the fact that I have yet to see a mod that mentions removing a color filter, I would say that there is not one in FO4 (I seem to remember threads on reddit around launch that praised the game for not having one). I can't give a definitive answer though.

Comment: Also, in FO4 you have dynamic weather that changes the prominent "color" of the world when rolling in.  I would say no, but cannot confirm.

Comment: Like @Mumford451 said, weather can change the color, but doesn't weather generally just change world lighting effects rather than adding a filter? I think the idea of having the game differently colored relies more on colored global lighting, so probably there are no color filters in the majority of the vanilla game.

Comment: Suggested edit: What lines of code, or assets, were necessary in F3 and NV (to have, or remove) for the color filters, and are any of those present in F4?

Comment: @Hattix If you happen to have a comparison screenshot for New Vegas without the text, please edit my question as the title obstructs the image slightly. [The Nexus Mods page](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/34888?tab=images) has only two images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made Fellout, and I made the FO3 and FNV screenshots the OP linked.

Fallout 3 uses post-processing known as "ImageSpaces", where the basic parameters of the rendered frame are changed. Things like brightness, saturation, contrast, radial blur, blur, etc. In Fellout, I pretty much neutralized them.

It also uses "ImageSpace Modifiers", which modify the imagespace of the scene. A Fatman explosion, for example, uses an imagespace modifier. They give you the effects on drugs wearing off, addictions, damage, head-cripple double vision, etc. These work on any imagespace and Fellout generally left these alone.

They are implemented in pixel shaders (SM2.0 nearly exclusively) and are a development of the very fake HDR system used in Oblivion.

Fallout 4 uses the exact same system. It still has imagespaces. It still has imagespace modifiers and it uses the hell out of them. It's not as blatant as Fallout 3 and everything being green, but it's still there.

Comment: How do you want me to do that?

Comment: Post a link to your answer to [your Nexus forums profile feed](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/user/915723-hattix/?tab=status) for instance. Posting directly to user pages doesn't appear to be possible on the the main website.

Comment: As much as I'm thinking I don't really have anything to prove to you, here you go:
https://upload.hattix.co.uk/uploads/nexus_profile.png